# Variance of Signum Function of Two Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $ X $ and $Y$ be two random variables with means $\mu_X$ and $\mu_Y$ respectively, as well as variances $\sigma_X$ and $\sigma_Y$ (all of which exist). I am interested in computing the following variance:

$$ Var[sgn(X-Y)]$$

where, of course, sgn denotes the [Signum Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function).

I am stuck because the closed form of $sgn(X-Y)$ is of the form $(X-Y)/|X-Y|$, at least for $X \ne Y$, and I don't see any straightforward ways of calculating the variance of this quantity. Does anyone know how to go about this?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: We may assume $Cov(X, Y)$ exists.

Comment: What do you know about the covariance?  And you'll need more from the distributions than just a mean and variance.

Comment: It may be easier to write $V[sgn(X-Y)]=E[(sgn(X-Y))^2] - E[sgn(X-Y)]^2$

Comment: @Paul I edited the question.

Comment: @Augustin You're right, please see my comment for the first answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that
$$\begin{align}
\operatorname E\mathrm{sgn}(X-Y)
& =-1\cdot\Pr(X<Y)+0\cdot\Pr(X<Y)+1\cdot\Pr(X>Y)
\\ & =\Pr(X>Y)-\Pr(X<Y)
\end{align}$$
and
$$\begin{align}
\operatorname E\mathrm{sgn}^2(X-Y)
& =(-1)^2\cdot\Pr(X<Y)+0^2\cdot\Pr(X<Y)+1^2\cdot\Pr(X>Y)
\\ & =\Pr(X>Y)+\Pr(X<Y)
\end{align}$$
using the [law of the unconscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician).
Hence,
$\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}\mathrm{sgn}(X-Y)
&=\Pr(X>Y)+\Pr(X<Y)-[\Pr(X>Y)-\Pr(X<Y)]^2.
\end{align}$

Comment: This does not directly answer my question, since I didn't say I know the distributions of X and Y, or their joint distribution (which I don't). I know they are continuous, hence $P(X \lt Y) = P(X \le Y)$, so it is easy to see that $E(sgn^2(X-Y)) = 1$, but I don't see an obvious way of computing $E(sgn(X-Y))$. But thank you for your answer.

Comment: Without further information about $X$ and $Y$ (i.i.d. for example), we can't go further than $P(X>Y)-P(X<Y)$.